# JavaScript/jQuery String Replace With Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Let's say I retrieve the value of a `<textarea>` using jQuery. How can I then replace a portion of the value using JavaScript/jQuery. For example:

string: `"Hey I'm $$zach$$"`

replace `$$zach$$` with `<i>Zach</i>`

And still keep the rest of the string intact?

Comment: I see that you've used `&lt;` etc in your example. Do you want to use `<` or `&lt;`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use a regex replace:

```
yourTextArea.value = yourTextArea.value.replace(/\$\$(.+?)\$\$/, '<i>$1</i>')
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
\$\$  two dollar signs
(     start a group to capture
.     a character
+     one or more
?     lazy capturing
)     end the group
\$\$  two more dollar signs
```

The capture group is then used in the string `'<i>$1</i>'`. `$1` refers to the group that the regex has captured.

Comment: what if for example, I "$$hi everyone$$" to be replaced?

Comment: Do not forget 'g' after '/'.
That worked when i added this letter only.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
str.replace(/\${2}(.*?)\${2}/g, "<I>$1</I>");
```

```
\${2} matches two $ characters
(.*?) matches your string to be wrapped
\${2} same as above
/g matches globally
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xAT/2/)

If you wanted something in jQuery:

```
$("#txt").val().replace(/\${2}(.*?)\${2}/g, "<I>$1</I>");
```

Markup:

```
<textarea id="txt">I'm $$Zach$$</textarea>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xAT/1/)

Wrap it in a function for best use:

```
var italics = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g, "<I>$1</I>");
}

italics($("#txt").val());
```

Seems like you want to make a syntax similar to Markdown. Why not just use a Markdown parser for your fields instead of reinventing the wheel?

[Showdown JS](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) is actively developed and you get the same Markdown syntax as with any other markdown syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Using the string `.replace` method will do.

```
.replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g, '<I>$1</I>')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this, change link and tag for extended linkify function :

```
String.prototype.linkify = function() {
    var wikipediaPattern = /<wikipedia>(.+?)<\/wikipedia>/g; 
    return this.replace(wikipediaPattern, '<a href="http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/$1">$1</a>');
}
```