# Check if a string has a span tag around it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var text='word <span>otherword</span> theotherword';
```

I will iterate all characters of text and check if a character has a span tag around it. In this case,  o-t-h-e-r-w-o-r-d characters have span tag. How can I check if span tag exists around characters?

I mean: i want to check all characters in the text through iterating them and see if it has span tag around the word that it belongs to.Because i need to replace characters with &nbsp except characters within words that have span element.

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span>otherword</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...
```

Comment: Use `$(text).filter('span').length`

Comment: but i want to check all characters through iterating them and see if it has span tag around the word that it belongs to.

Comment: If you insist on doing it that way you cannot use jQuery. Tell us *why* you want to do that? Maybe there's a simpler way to accomplish what you want to do once you know that some text has a span around it?

Comment: You can use regex instead of iterating the string and find the patterns in your case `<span>sometext</span>` this will help.

Comment: i need to replace  characters with &nbsp  except characters within words that have span element.

Comment: you can use strreplace along with regex. This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137562/javascript-jquery-string-replace-with-regex

Comment: For regex reference you can see a sample here https://regex101.com/r/dE6pH3/1

Comment: Do you need to replace words/strings that CONTAIN &nbsp; or do you need to replace all words that are not inside span-tags with an &nbsp?

Comment: this: "do you need to replace all words that are not inside span-tags with an &nbsp?"

Answer (score 2):

> i need to replace characters with &nbsp except characters within words that have span element

You can simply use regex:

```
<span>.*&nbsp;.*</span>
```

and `String.prototype.replace`.

The following snippet replaces all `&nbsp;` only within `<span>` tags with plain whitespace.

```js
var str = "&nbsp; outside somechars<span>asdasd&nbsp;qweqwe</span>";

document.body.innerText = str.replace(/(<span>.*)&nbsp;(.*<\/span>)/g, "$1 $2");
```

Comment: OP's default string doesn't contain `</span>`: `var text='word <span>otherword<span> theotherword';`

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("p:contains(in)")) {
    $("p").text().replace("<span>","&nbsp;");
$("p").text().replace("</span>","&nbsp;");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>word <span>otherword</span> theotherword</p>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does not do what **@tablex** asked for.