# Is there any way to replace text that defines a value in array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here the HTML code:

```
<textarea>I have played arr[0] and i always try to arr[1] in my arr[2]</textarea>
```

Here is the array:

```
var arr = ["football", "drive", "city"]
```

How to replace `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` with the correct values from the array `arr` using `jQuery` on click to create a new `textarea` with the new content like that:

```
<textarea>I have played football and i always try to drive in my city</textarea>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: you can use this in jQuery but question is not clear `$.each(arr,function(i,v) {

});`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm now checking your answer. I have edited the question to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex for this:

```
yourTextArea.value = yourTextArea.value.replace(/arr\[(.+?)\]/g, function (orig, index) {
    return arr[index];
})
```

This captures the index from the `"arr[x]"` strings, and uses the index to get the data from the `arr` array. The parentheses define a capturing group, and the `.+?` does the capturing itself.

It's quick and dirty :)

For reference, I stole the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137595/2102532).

---

By the way you would be better off using an i18n library instead of hacking manually. There are a couple of gettext-like solutions for JavaScript too.

Comment: This of course would also replace `apiratesaysarr[ because that's just what they say :-]`.

Comment: Of course, proper sanitation is missing from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm now checking your answer. I have edited the question to be clear.

Comment: @h2ooooooo `apiratesay` `arrr` not `arr :]`

Comment: @EmmaLeonil My originality wasn't at it's top point with that comment. I was too lazy to google "words that end in arr" :-)